# loop inside loop to search ranges of IP from AS

Tags: bash, for-loop

I'm trying to get all the ranges of operators by AS path searching the AS from HE website, here you have some tests I'm doing, but I'm not able to make it working:

```
#!/bin/bash

url=http://bgp.he.net/country/ES
text=$(curl -s --user-agent "Mozilla/4.0" "$url")


#for i in $(echo $text |grep -o -P 'AS.{0,5}' |egrep -v -i ",|\"|<|>|O|N|I|e|R|\.|-" |sort -u)
#       do
#          for i2 in $(/usr/bin/whois -h whois.radb.net '!g"$i"' | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -n -k1,1 -k2,2 -k3,3 -k4,4 |grep /);
#          do echo $i2;
#          done;
#done


test=(AS9165 AS9192)

for i in $test;
        do
           for i2 in $((/usr/bin/whois -h whois.radb.net '!g$(echo $i)' | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -n -k1,1 -k2,2 -k3,3 -k4,4 |grep /));
           do echo $i2;
           done;
done
```

The commented lines are the ones I'm working, to do the tests in a more tiny consult I created array test, but the info has to take from grep and egrep command.

Both commands are working, I've got problems on looping.

Any help will be thankful!

Thanks you much folks! :)

Comment: What is this `'!g$(echo $i)'` parameter for? Is this the `whois` query? It must be separated from options by double dashes `--`. The variable `$i` is within single quotes. It will not be evaluated, neither will the `$()` because they are inside single quotes.

Comment: I am assuming there is no output otherwise you would have posted the output.

Comment: does `echo $text |grep -o -P 'AS.{0,5}' |egrep -v -i ",|\"|<|>|O|N|I|e|R|\.|-" |sort -u` executed by itself return a usable list?  If not, start with 2 cmds around 1 pipe, then keep adding pipes until it breaks, then you know what to fix. Good luck.

Comment: alvits, '!g$(echo $i)' takes the AS number and returns all the network ranges of this AS path. shellter, yes, it returns an usable list of AS path from spain (in this case), to make it work you have to execute the script.